# Where to close a JDBC Connection while I want to return the ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, resultset

It seems that the `ResultSet` will be automatically closed when I close the `Connection`.
But I want to return the `ResultSet` and use it in another method, then I don't know where to close `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`.

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql, String[] getValue)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        conn = getConn();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (getValue != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < getValue.length; i++)
            {
                pstmt.setString(i + 1, getValue[i]);
            }
        }
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        closeAll(conn, pstmt, rs);
    }
    return rs;
}
```

I've moved `closeAll(conn, pstmt, null);` into catch block because I found that if I put it in finally block I'll lost my `rs` immediately just before it returns.
Now when I want to close the `rs`, I can't close the `conn` and `pstmt`. Is there any solution?

Comment: are you attempting to stream the resultSet, i.e. avoid simply reading all of the results into some sort of collection and returning that?

Comment: Off topic, why is every one using that brace style?!!! This is Java not C#

Comment: Thank you all you warmhearteds!It's nearly morning at China but I'm too touched by you and your brilliant answers to sleep.This is my first question at Stackoverflow.com .I really appreciate your help.
I will be a frequenter here!

Comment: @Oscar This must be Jon Skeet's fault. I hate him for that :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `CachedRowSet` for holding info after disconnecting

```
Connection con = ...
ResultSet rs = ...

CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
rowset.populate(rs);

con.close()
```

Comment: After reading the API of CachedRowSet,I found this seems to be the easiest way.I think I'll take this answer.

Answer (score 20):

One clean way of coding this is to pass in an object that has a callback method that takes a result set.

Your other method creates the object with the callback method with it's resultSet handling code, and passes that to the method that executes the SQL.

That way, your SQL & DB code stays where it belongs, your result set handling logic is closer to where you use the data, and your SQL code cleans up when it should.

```
  interface ResultSetCallBack{
    void handleResultSet(ResultSet r);
  }

  void executeQuery(..., ResultSetCallBack cb){
    //get resultSet r ...
    cb.handleResultSet(r);
    //close connection
  }

  void printReport(){
    executeQuery(..., new ResultSetCallBack(){
      public void handleResultSet(ResultSet r) {
        //do stuff with r here
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You should **never** pass `ResultSet` (or `Statement` or `Connection`) into the public outside the method block where they are to be acquired **and** closed to avoid resource leaks. A common practice is just to map the `ResultSet` to a `List<Data>` where `Data` is just a javabean object representing the data of interest.

Here's a basic example:

```
public class Data {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer value;
    // Add/generate public getters + setters.
}
```

and here's a basic example of how to handle it correctly:

```
public List<Data> list() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, value FROM data");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            data.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            data.setValue(resultSet.getInt("value"));
            list.add(data);
        }
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    return list;
}
```

you can use it as follows:

```
List<Data> list = dataDAO.list();
```

To learn more about the best practices with JDBC you may find [this basic kickoff article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful as well.

Comment: This requires to store everything in memory.  When you have lots of rows, unless you intend to keep the data in memory, it is really interesting to pass an unread rowset to whatever you want to do with it, be it write it to a file, filter it or compute a sum, and consume it as you process it.

Comment: @FlorianF Just use LIMIT/OFFSET.

Comment: That introduces a lot of complexity, it multiplies the database accesses and breaks the atomicity of the request.  You might get duplicates because a row was deleted at the top of the list between two "slice" requests.

Comment: @FlorianF Just use JPA.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it right now, the connection would never close which would cause problems later (if not immediately) for your program and the RDBMS.  It would be better to create a Java class to hold the fields from the ResultSet and return that.  The ResultSet is linked to the connection, so returning it and closing the connection is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `ResultSet` after you've closed `Connection` and/or `PreparedStatement`.
So, you need to pass an object on which to make a callback into this method.

All cleanup should be done in `finally` blocks.

Rewrite it like this

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(
    String sql,
    String[] getValue,
    CallbackObj cbObj
  ) throws SQLException
{
  final Connection conn = getConn( );

  try
  {
    final PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    try
    {
      if (getValue != null)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < getValue.length; i++)
        {
          pstmt.setString(i + 1, getValue[i]);
        }
      }

      final ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

      try
      {
        cbObj.processResultSet( rs );
      }
      finally
      {
        // You may want to handle SQLException
        // declared by close
        rs.close( );
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      // You may want to handle SQLException
      // declared by close
      pstmt.close( );
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    // You may want to handle SQLException
    // declared by close
    conn.close( );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `ResultSet.getStatement` to retrieve the `Statement`, and `Statement.getConnection` to retrieve the `Connection`.

From these you can write a `closeResultSet` utility method that will close all 3 for you, given nothing but the `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 3):

> Where to close a JDBC Connection while I want to return the ResultSet

Actually, you've almost answered that question yourself. As you experimented, closing the [`Connection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) will release the JDBC resources associated to it (at least, this is how things should work). So, if you want to return a [`ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (I'll come back on this later), you need to close the connection "later". One way to do this would be obviously to pass a connection to your method, something like this:

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(Connection conn, String sql, String[] getValue);
```

The problem is that I don't really know what is your final goal and why you need so low level stuff so I'm not sure this is a good advice. Unless if you are writing a low level JDBC framework (and please, don't tell me you are not doing this), I would actually not recommend returning a [`ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). For example, if you want to feed some business class, return some JDBC-independent object or a collection of them as other have advised instead of a [`ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Also bear in mind that a [`RowSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) **is** a [`ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) so if you should not use a [`ResultSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) then you should not use a [`RowSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html).

Personally, I think you should use some helper class instead of reinventing the wheel. While Spring may be overkill and has a bit of learning curve (too much if you don't know it at all), Spring is not the only way to go and I strongly suggest to look at [Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/). More specifically, look at [`QueryRunner`](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html) and especially this [`query()`](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
public <T> T query(String sql,
                   ResultSetHandler<T> rsh,
                   Object... params)
        throws SQLException
```

As you can see, this method allows to pass a [`ResultSetHandler`](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/ResultSetHandler.html) which exposes a callback method to convert `ResultSets` into other objects as described in [z5h's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910049/where-to-close-a-jdbc-connection-while-i-want-to-return-the-resultset/1910081#1910081) and DbUtils provides several implementations, just pick up the one that will suit your needs. Also have a look at the utility methods of the [`DbUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html) class, for example the various `DbUnit.close()` that you may find handy to close JDBC resources.

Really, unless you have very good reasons to do so (and I'd be curious to know them), don't write yet another JDBC framework, use an existing solution, it will save you some pain and, more important, some bugs and you'll benefit from proven good design. Even for low level stuff, there are existing (and simple) solutions as we saw. At least, check it out.

Answer (score 3):

The cleaner way is to use **CachedRowSetImpl**. But on MySQL 5.x+ there are some bugs with selecting columns by name or label.

For use with MySQL use this version:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17399059/1978096

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't handle with JDBC at the lower level. Use a framework like [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html) instead, it will handle all required `close()` operations for you.

Comment: This is a very good point.  Using a framework like Spring keeps you from having to reinvent the wheel all the time and focus on building the car.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting up Spring on a new project without any prior experience is pretty much doomed to fail.

Comment: indeed. JDBC isn't always bad.

Comment: You don't have to "set up spring". For using it's JDBC layer it's simply an additional jar. No extra config is needed.

Comment: I'm learning JDBC right now ,is it possible to just skip this part and study into Spring?

Comment: @tangens It looks like you have to do quite a bit to set up Spring. Here is an example I saw for working with one table's data - http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jdbc-transactions-example

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you do something more like this:

```
public List<Map> executeQuery(Connection connection, String sql) throws SQLException
{
    List<Map> rows = new ArrayList<Map>();

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try
    {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = stmt.execute();
        int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Map<String, Object> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; ++i)
            {
                String column = rs.getColumnName(i+1);
                Object value = rs.getObject(i+1);
                row.put(column, value);
            }
            rows.add(row);
        }
    } 
    finally
    {
        close(rs);
        close(stmt);
    }

    return rows;
}

public static void close(Statement s)
{
    try
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void close(ResultSet rs)
{
    try
    {
        if (rs != null)
        {
            rs.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```