# Are there any good CachedRowSet implementations other than the proprietary Sun one?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cachedrowset

I am investigating using [`javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) in part of my application, however I can only find information on using the proprietary sun implementation [`com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.html) or Oracle specific implementations.

The sun implementation is [unsupported and subject to change](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html). Using this could also cause problems if I want to deploy to non-Sun virtual machines in the future, and finally it leaves unsuppressible warnings in our build logs which can mask other warnings.

Is there an open source alternative implementation that we I can deploy with my application that will work well across multiple databases? At a minimum something that supports MySQL.

Comment: The link you cited specifically applies to `sun.*` packages. It does not apply to `com.sun.*` packages.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8217493/642706

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You shouldn't be directly instantiating implementation of CachedRowSet -- use its Provider to obtain an instance: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html (available since JDK7)

In fact, CachedRowSet's interface and related factory are standard/portable.

Something like the following shoud do the trick:

```
CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
crs.populate(myResultSet);
```

Comment: This wasn't available when I asked the original question but it is good to know that this gap is addressed by Java now, thanks.

Comment: Google seems to have made an update and the RowSetProvider class is no longer whitelisted: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my improved implementation of **CachedRowSetImpl** to support MySQL 5.x names and labels. Based on the implementation of this guy [Re: Regression from 2.1.6](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-java/2012/7/10715.html)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Ref;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl;

import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;

public class FixedCachedRowSetImplMySql extends CachedRowSetImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9067504047398250113L;
    private RowSetMetaDataImpl RowSetMD;

    public FixedCachedRowSetImpl() throws SQLException {
        super();
    }

    public FixedCachedRowSetImpl(Hashtable env) throws SQLException {
        super(env);
    }

    private int getColIdxByName(String name) throws SQLException {
        RowSetMD = (RowSetMetaDataImpl) this.getMetaData();
        int cols = RowSetMD.getColumnCount();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= cols; ++i) {
            String colLabel = RowSetMD.getColumnLabel(i);
            String colName  = RowSetMD.getColumnName(i);
            if (colName != null) if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(colName) || name.equalsIgnoreCase(RowSetMD.getTableName(i) + "." + colName)) {               
                return (i);
            }
            else if (colLabel != null) if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(colLabel)) {
                return (i);
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        throw new SQLException(resBundle.handleGetObject("cachedrowsetimpl.invalcolnm").toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> toCollection(String column) throws SQLException {
        return toCollection(getColIdxByName(column));
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getString(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBoolean(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public byte getByte(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getByte(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public short getShort(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getShort(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getInt(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public long getLong(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getLong(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloat(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getFloat(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public double getDouble(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getDouble(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(String columnName, int scale) throws SQLException {
        return getBigDecimal(getColIdxByName(columnName), scale);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBytes(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Date getDate(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getDate(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Time getTime(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getTime(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getTimestamp(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.io.InputStream getAsciiStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getAsciiStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));

    }

    @Override
    public java.io.InputStream getUnicodeStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getUnicodeStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.io.InputStream getBinaryStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBinaryStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getObject(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public int findColumn(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getColIdxByName(columnName);
    }

    @Override
    public java.io.Reader getCharacterStream(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getCharacterStream(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getBigDecimal(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean columnUpdated(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return columnUpdated(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateNull(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        updateNull(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBoolean(String columnName, boolean x) throws SQLException {
        updateBoolean(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateByte(String columnName, byte x) throws SQLException {
        updateByte(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateShort(String columnName, short x) throws SQLException {
        updateShort(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateInt(String columnName, int x) throws SQLException {
        updateInt(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateLong(String columnName, long x) throws SQLException {
        updateLong(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFloat(String columnName, float x) throws SQLException {
        updateFloat(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDouble(String columnName, double x) throws SQLException {
        updateDouble(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBigDecimal(String columnName, BigDecimal x) throws SQLException {
        updateBigDecimal(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateString(String columnName, String x) throws SQLException {
        updateString(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBytes(String columnName, byte x[]) throws SQLException {
        updateBytes(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDate(String columnName, java.sql.Date x) throws SQLException {
        updateDate(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTime(String columnName, java.sql.Time x) throws SQLException {
        updateTime(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTimestamp(String columnName, java.sql.Timestamp x) throws SQLException {
        updateTimestamp(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAsciiStream(String columnName, java.io.InputStream x, int length) throws SQLException {
        updateAsciiStream(getColIdxByName(columnName), x, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBinaryStream(String columnName, java.io.InputStream x, int length) throws SQLException {
        updateBinaryStream(getColIdxByName(columnName), x, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCharacterStream(String columnName, java.io.Reader reader, int length) throws SQLException {
        updateCharacterStream(getColIdxByName(columnName), reader, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObject(String columnName, Object x, int scale) throws SQLException {
        updateObject(getColIdxByName(columnName), x, scale);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObject(String columnName, Object x) throws SQLException {
        updateObject(getColIdxByName(columnName), x);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject(String columnName, java.util.Map<String, Class<?>> map) throws SQLException {
        return getObject(getColIdxByName(columnName), map);
    }

    @Override
    public Ref getRef(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getRef(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public Blob getBlob(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getBlob(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public Clob getClob(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getClob(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public Array getArray(String colName) throws SQLException {
        return getArray(getColIdxByName(colName));
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Date getDate(String columnName, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
        return getDate(getColIdxByName(columnName), cal);
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Time getTime(String columnName, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
        return getTime(getColIdxByName(columnName), cal);
    }

    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(String columnName, Calendar cal) throws SQLException {
        return getTimestamp(getColIdxByName(columnName), cal);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateRef(String columnName, java.sql.Ref ref) throws SQLException {
        updateRef(getColIdxByName(columnName), ref);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateClob(String columnName, Clob c) throws SQLException {
        updateClob(getColIdxByName(columnName), c);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBlob(String columnName, Blob b) throws SQLException {
        updateBlob(getColIdxByName(columnName), b);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateArray(String columnName, Array a) throws SQLException {
        updateArray(getColIdxByName(columnName), a);
    }

    @Override
    public java.net.URL getURL(String columnName) throws SQLException {
        return getURL(getColIdxByName(columnName));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. The class name and constructor names don't agree. You should add some commentary explaining what problems this fixes.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle Implementation  *Is* Open-Source

The question incorrectly states that the Oracle RowSet implementation is proprietary. It is not; it already is open-source.

The source code is released as free software under the [GNU General Public Library (GPL) version 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Version_2) license with ["Classpath" exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception#The_classpath_exception). Read [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/1a3de3cdc684/src/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java) to see the license.

So they cannot be withdrawn. You and others are free to maintain or modify these classes provided you follow the terms of the GPL.

## JDBC Driver Implementation

Also, some JDBC drivers provide an implementation of RowSet. I do not know if any are open-source, but that would be one avenue to explore.