# Implementations of RowSet, CachedRowSet etc

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, rowset, cachedrowset

Until today I was working with `ResultSet` when handling results from queries. But today I read a little about [`RowSet`](http://[%60RowSet%60](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html)) and [`CachedRowset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) and I realized they can serve my purposes better. While in all the examples I read where `RowSet` and `CachedRowSet` were referred to as object, when I tried it myself in my code I realized those are interfaces and in the examples they use some implementation of those interfaces.

Now my question is where do I find those implementations, and is there something official?

Do I need to download them or do they come with the JDK?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2228462/642706

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The implementations are JRE specific. Oracle (Sun) JRE comes with a bunch of implementations:

- `com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl`
- `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`
- `com.sun.rowset.WebRowSetImpl`
- `com.sun.rowset.FilteredRowSetImpl`
- `com.sun.rowset.JoinRowSetImpl`

In Java 1.6 and before, you'd need to construct them yourself:

```
JdbcRowSet rowSet = new JdbcRowSetImpl();
rowSet.setDataSourceName("jdbc/dbname");
// Or
rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:vendor://host:port/dbname");
rowSet.setUsername("username");
rowSet.setPassword("password");

rowSet.setCommand("SELECT id, name, value FROM tbl");
rowSet.execute();

while (rowSet.next()) {
    // ...
}
```

In Java 1.7 you can get them by a `javax.sql.rowset` factory so that you're not dependent of underlying JRE implementation and that you can finetune the implementation of choice if necessary:

```
RowSetFactory rowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
JdbcRowSet rowSet = rowSetFactory.createJdbcRowSet();
// ...
```

It only doesn't provide a possibility to pass a `ResultSet` on construction. Those implementations doesn't ship with the average JDBC driver (at least, MySQL and PostgreSQL have none). It's basically an extra (optional) layer over JDBC API as the package name prefix `javax` hints.

Note that if you get that far by looking into rowsets, then you might want to consider to look into an ORM instead, such as Hibernate or JPA. They provide first/second level cache possibilities.

#### See also:

- [JDBC Guide - Chapter 10 - RowSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/rowsetImpl.html)
- [JDBC RowSet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html), by Oracle
- [Java 8 `javax.sql.rowset` package summary](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/package-summary.html)
- [Source code in OpenJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c35571198602/src/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/) for Oracle’s [com.sun.rowset](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/index.html) implementation, Gnu GPL 2 license with [Classpath exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception#The_classpath_exception)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I don't have all those Impl classes, do I need to download them? If I do, it makes things a little complicated.
I'll be learning ORM later in my training, I've just stumbled upon RowSet, and I thought it'd be better to use it rather than ResultSet which requires an open connection.

Comment: They're present in the JRE/JRK. Perhaps you're using an IDE and it is suppressing the import of restricted API? It's configureable in IDE's preferences.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse (Indigo) and I can only see com.sun.rowset.internal and com.sun.rowset.providers

Comment: Add this line: `import com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl;` What does the warning/error message say? If it errors, then you can configure it by setting *Window > Preferences > Java > Errors/Warnings > Deprecated and restricted API > Forbidden reference* to *Ignore* or *Warning* instead of *Error*.

Comment: Be aware that some JDBC drivers also provide an implementation of RowSet.

Answer (score 0):

The `RowSet` and `CachedRowSet` are implemented by the JDBC drivers.

Your database provider delivers the drivers e.g. [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) or [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). However those drivers only make sense in conjunction with an actual database.

Comment: I have the ojdbc14.jar, but it doesn't contain oracle.jdbc.rowset which contains OracleCachedRowSet and all the others.

Does it have anything to do with the version or something like that?

Comment: The ojdbc14.jar is a java 1.4 driver. The CachedRowSet was introduced with java 1.5. You need to get a JDBC 3.0 or higher driver.

Comment: True, a JDBC driver vendor may provide a RowSet implementation. But Sun/Oracle has also released source code for implementations under the [GNU General Public License version 2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Comment: It was introduced in JDBC 3, Java 1.4. I have never seen a vendor implementation of `CachedRowSet`

Comment: Dear Down-Voters: Please leave a criticism along with your vote. This Answer seems to me to be correct, valid, and valuable.

Comment: @EJP See the [Answer by BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218122/642706) for links to an implementation by Sun and maintained by Oracle, bundled with their implementation of Java. See [this similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2228462/642706) for implementations specifically for MySQL and Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with the JDK.

In JDK 10, the jar is:
jdk-10.0.2/lib/jrt-fs.jar

And the package/class inside the jar is:
javax.sql.RowSet.class

Daniel Pinheiro

danielpm1982@gmail.com

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add rt.jar in Eclipse Java Build Path. Then you see all the implemention class. Else you can remove the restriction from Eclipse which is not allowing to access rt.jar from jdk.
Works for me. I was using jdk1.6 and Eclipse Luna.