# I can't find where my resultset.next method implementation available in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to know about the implementation of

```
ResultSet rs=cn.executeQuery();
rs.next();
```

now where next is implemented.

I can not find where my `ResultSet` interface next() method implementation available in JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

All database should support common operations of executing a query, traverse  through the resultset, reading each column in a result, getting a connection,closing a connection ...etc.

So these standard operations are made as interface methods by Java.
ow the vendors who provide database drivers, implement this interface and hence they have to write their own implementation for each methods.

so you can find implementation in a jar that you are using for database connection like sqljdbc, odbc etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)   is a interface, It doesn't have any method implementation.

You need to see the implemented classes.

[That implementation classes are JRE specific.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217493/implementations-of-rowset-cachedrowset-etc)

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet` is an *interface* for supporting all the common database operations.

Different vendors such as `Oracle, MySQL, HSQLDB` all have implemented their own drivers which contain the actual vendor specific implementation.

These drivers are present in the form of `jars` which you have to add to your project classpath to be able to communicate with that vendor specific database.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but i give some code try this :

```
 String query = "SELECT * from sss;
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next())
    {
            String xx = rs.getString("x");
    }
```