# Query results without storing in POJO?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Can I use query results (Spring JDBC) from database without storing in Java POJO?

I have many queries to use in my project? I don't want to map those big query columns names to POJO varaiables 
Please suggest some way?

Comment: Yo are not precise enough. How do you want store data ? And what are your data types you want to go up from your queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `RowSet`

You can get a [`RowSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) from your `ResultSet` obtained via JDBC.

The [`CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) extension of that `RowSet` interface is for storing the rows of data in memory within your JVM. You may continue to access the `CachedRowSet` even after closing your connection to the database.

Oracle provides an open-source free-of-cost ([GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpl_2) 2 license) implementation of `CachedRowSet`. This may be bundled with your Java installation. If not, you can obtain the source-code separately. See this Question, [*Implementations of RowSet, CachedRowSet etc*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8217493/642706).

For more information, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html).

Surprisingly, the `RowSet` interface and its implementations have garnered little attention. They seem like a good idea to me. I have personally used the Oracle-provided implementation of `CachedRowSet` successfully in a small project.

Answer (score 1):

How about making queries to only those columns you are interested in ? 
The essence of having mapping is to do less. Or else you would need to use plain Java jdbc. 
[edit]

There is no connection between you objects and the database table(s). Either you explicitly mention the tables and columns if you are using plain jdbc. OR . you do a pre-mapping so that you don't need to write table and column names all the time, which is error prone.

To summarise

- No mapping

  - Use plain jdbc [POJO]
- Pre-Mapped

  - xml configuration
  - Annotation

When you use xml configuration, it may look POJO but it is not.

Comment: That means I still need to use POJO if I use Spring Jdbc right?