# What is Different between of JdbcRowSet ,CachedRowSet and WebRowSet

Tags: java, mysql

I am so confused What is jdbcRowSet, CachedRowSet and WebRowSet. Please Give Me best Answer.

Comment: What part of their respective Javadoc didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

Refer below for clear examples of all three. I think you will get clear picture about these [`RowSet`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) interfaces.

## JDBCRowSet

A connected rowset that serves mainly as a thin wrapper around a ResultSet object to make a JDBC driver look like a JavaBeans component.

Example:

```
JdbcRowSet jdbcRs = new JdbcRowSetImpl(); 
jdbcRs.setUsername("scott"); 
jdbcRs.setPassword("tiger"); 
jdbcRs.setUrl("jdbc:oracle://localhost:3306/test"); 
jdbcRs.setCommand("select * from employee"); 
jdbcRs.execute(); 
while(jdbcRs.next()) { 
System.out.println(jdbcRs.getString("emp_name")); 
}
```

## CachedRowSet

A disconnected rowset that caches its data in memory; not suitable for very large data sets, but an ideal way to provide thin Java clients.

Example :

```
CachedRowSet cachedRs = new CachedRowSetImpl(); 
cachedRs.setUsername("scott"); 
cachedRs.setPassword("tiger"); 
cachedRs.setUrl("jdbc:oracle://localhost:3306/test"); 
cachedRs.setCommand("select * from employee"); 
cachedRs.setPageSize(4); 
cachedRs.execute(); 
while (cachedRs.nextPage()) { 
while (cachedRs.next()) { 
System.out.println(cachedRs.getString("emp_name"));
} 
}
```

## WebRowSet

A connected rowset that uses the HTTP protocol internally to talk to a Java servlet that provides data access; 
used to make it possible for thin web clients to retrieve and possibly update a set of rows.

## Implementations

For more info about implementations of these [`RowSet`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) interfaces, see this related Question, [*Implementations of RowSet, CachedRowSet etc*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8217493/642706).

Comment: Thanks you Vivek kumar.

Comment: More info: You will need to find an implementation of these [`RowSet`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) interfaces. Sun provided an open-source implementation. You may find others too. Unfortunately, despite their seeming usefulness, much of the database community has ignored these RowSet interfaces, apparently out of ignorance.