# JAVA ERROR : package com.sun.rowset is not visible : com.sun.rowset is declared in module java.sql.rowset, which does not export it

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-9, java-module

I'm simply try to run this code:

```
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    }
}
```

When I run it I get:

> Error:(1, 15) java: package com.sun.rowset is not visible   (package
>   com.sun.rowset is declared in module java.sql.rowset, which does not
>   export it)

I'm using IntelliJ and I tried to import rs2xml.jar, and that still doesnt help.

Comment: Which JDK are you using in this project?

Comment: @Andremoniy 9.0.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of Java 9, you can not access this class directly. And in the ideal way you shouldn't do that. That is because this class's package is not exported in the module `javax.sql.rowset`.

The proper way to do that in Java 9+ is the use of [`RowSetProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html) to access a [`RowSetFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetFactory.html) to produce an instance of an implementation of [`CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)

```
import javax.sql.rowset.*; 

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
    }
}
```

To understand that we can go to the module description (`module-info.java`) and find a list of exported packages:

```
exports javax.sql.rowset;
exports javax.sql.rowset.serial;
exports javax.sql.rowset.spi;
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be used with Java 10

Instead of

```
CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
```

use

```
CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers here, it is important to note that you should *never* use `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`, even in Java 8.

As explained at [Are there any good CachedRowSet implementations other than the Sun one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228462/are-there-any-good-cachedrowset-implementations-other-than-the-proprietary-sun-o) , the `RowSetProvider` is the standard way to obtain a `CachedRowSet`.

Packages from `sun` are [internal and subject to change](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html). They should never be used except by JDK developers.