# Excluding dependency does not help to fix "The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-9, java-module

When trying to setup a project with a Java version > 9 I came across a problem with dependencies and the Java module system. I know that there are some posts regarding this topic (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426105/how-to-solve-dependency-and-package-issues-migrating-java-8-code-to-java-11) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10/53824670#53824670)), but the solutions (exclude packages from dependencies) don't seem to help in my case. 
On some imports related to XML parsing, I get the following error `The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml`

I used the "Open Type" dialog and found that there are in fact two providers for e.g. org.w3c.dom.Document.
[image: Two providers of org.w3c.dom.Document]

This *rmlmapper-4.9.1.jar* is currently the only maven dependency in my project and I tried to exclude xml-apis as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286825/the-package-org-w3c-dom-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed-java). I also added org.w3c.dom as you can see.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.ugent.rml</groupId>
        <artifactId>rmlmapper</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help and the error persists. Note that I can build the project but get errors at runtime. Am I excluding the wrong packages? I couldn't find a package providing `org.w3c.dom` using `mvn dependency:tree` so how can I find the packages that need to be excluded?

Answer (score 1):

From the Eclipse snapshot you provide, it seems the package `org.w3c.dom` is embedded in the `rmlmapper` dependency Jar itself (the Jar is probably bundling its own dependencies in it). Therefore the `exclusion` will not work as it only excludes transitive dependencies (not bundled packages). Even though [it's possible to exclude the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955820/exclude-java-package-from-dependency-jar), another approach is to exclude the `java.xml` module with the `--limit-modules` option as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10/53824670#53824670). Note that you might have to do this with other modules if `rmlmapper` also bundles other JDK classes.

Either way, the best solution is to contact the owner of the `rmlmapper` library and let them know of the issue on Java 9+, as maybe they did not upgrade their project to support that version.