# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have a code which is inserting data into table after processing but again and again I am getting error

> Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Here is my code.

```
 try {
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from asteriskcdrdb.sp1");
        while (rs.next()) {
            AreaCode = rs.getString("AreaCode");
            //System.out.println(AreaCode);
            String Pulse = rs.getString("Pulse");
            Rate = rs.getInt("Rate/pulse");
            // System.out.println(Rate);
            if (AreaCode.equals(str)) {
                System.out.println("Hii");
                try {
                    Connection conn = null;
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    rst = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from cdr where src ='9035020090'");
                    while (rst.next()) {
                        calldate = rst.getString("calldate");
                        // System.out.println(calldate);
                        clid = rst.getString("clid");
                        src = rst.getString("src");
                        dst = rst.getString("dst");
                        dcontext = rst.getString("dcontext");
                        channel = rst.getString("channel");
                        dstchannel = rst.getString("dstchannel");
                        lastapp = rst.getString("lastapp");
                        lastdata = rst.getString("lastdata");
                        duration = rst.getString("duration");
                        //System.out.println(duration);
                        dur = Integer.parseInt(duration);
                        //System.out.println(dur);
                        data.add(dur);
                        billsec = rst.getString("billsec");
                        disposition = rst.getString("disposition");
                        amaflags = rst.getString("amaflags");
                        accountcode = rst.getString("accountcode");
                        uniqueid = rst.getString("uniqueid");
                        userfield = rst.getString("userfield");
                        int newcost = checktime(dur, Rate);
                        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into cdrcost (
         calldate,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,
         dstchannel,lastapp, lastdata,duration,billsec,
         disposition,amaflags,accountcode,uniqueid,
         userfield,cdrcost) values ('" + calldate + "','" + 
         clid + "','" + src + "','" + dst + "','" + dcontext 
         + "','" + channel + "','" + dstchannel + "','" + 
         lastapp + "','" + lastdata + "','" + duration + "','" + 
         billsec + "','" + disposition + "','" + amaflags 
          + "','" + accountcode + "','" + uniqueid + "','" + userfield  
         + "','" + newcost + "')");
                     }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            } else if (AreaCode.equals(str2)) {
                System.out.println("Hii2");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static int checktime(int dur, int Rate) {
    int cost = 0;

    // System.out.println(c);
    int min = 60;

    int quotient = dur / min;
    // System.out.println(quotient);

    int reminder = dur % min;
    //  System.out.println(reminder);

    if (reminder > 0) {
        quotient = quotient + 1;
        // System.out.println(quotient);

        // System.out.println(cost);
    }
    cost = quotient * Rate;
    return cost;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before giving you an answer, you should know some basic things about database access and JDBC:

- You **must not** create many connections to access the database in a big operation. If you need to read, insert, update or delete data in a single method, you should use only 1 connection. Opening a connection is a great cost operation. If you don't notice it yet is because you're in a single-user (you) environment.
- Every `Statement` uses one *or more* `ResultSet`s. Since you're a beginner, assume that each `Statement` will have a single `ResultSet`. If you modify the data in a `Statement`, the `ResultSet` bounded to this `Statement` will be closed and can't be used in future operations. That's why you have the problem (as stated in other answers).
- If you will execute a SQL statement that will use parameters, use a `PreparedStatement`. Otherwise, your application will be prone to SQL Injection attack (i.e. a hacker could shut down your database server, you and me know that's a bad thing to happen).
- You should close the resources after using them. This means, you should close the `ResultSet`s, `Statement`s and `Connection` (in this order).

Based in all these notes, your code will change to this:

```
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from asteriskcdrdb.sp1");
    while (rs.next()) {
        AreaCode = rs.getString("AreaCode");
        String Pulse = rs.getString("Pulse");
        Rate = rs.getInt("Rate/pulse");
        if (AreaCode.equals(str)) {
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rst = null;
            PreparedStatement insSt = null;
            try {
                //using the first connection
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rst = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from cdr where src ='9035020090'");
                while (rst.next()) {
                    calldate = rst.getString("calldate");
                    clid = rst.getString("clid");
                    src = rst.getString("src");
                    dst = rst.getString("dst");
                    dcontext = rst.getString("dcontext");
                    channel = rst.getString("channel");
                    dstchannel = rst.getString("dstchannel");
                    lastapp = rst.getString("lastapp");
                    lastdata = rst.getString("lastdata");
                    duration = rst.getString("duration");
                    dur = Integer.parseInt(duration);
                    data.add(dur);
                    billsec = rst.getString("billsec");
                    disposition = rst.getString("disposition");
                    amaflags = rst.getString("amaflags");
                    accountcode = rst.getString("accountcode");
                    uniqueid = rst.getString("uniqueid");
                    userfield = rst.getString("userfield");
                    int newcost = checktime(dur, Rate);
                    //every ? is a parameter in the query
                    insSt = con.prepareStatement(
                        "insert into cdrcost (calldate,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel, dstchannel, lastapp, lastdata,duration,billsec, disposition,amaflags,accountcode,uniqueid, userfield,cdrcost) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    //setting every parameter
                    insSt.setObject(1, calldate);
                    insSt.setObject(2, clid);
                    insSt.setObject(3, src);
                    insSt.setObject(4, dst);
                    insSt.setObject(5, dcontext);
                    insSt.setObject(6, channel);
                    insSt.setObject(7, dstchannel);
                    insSt.setObject(8, lastapp);
                    insSt.setObject(9, lastdata);
                    insSt.setObject(10, duration);
                    insSt.setObject(11, billsec);
                    insSt.setObject(12, disposition);
                    insSt.setObject(13, amaflags);
                    insSt.setObject(14, accountcode);
                    insSt.setObject(15, uniqueid);
                    insSt.setObject(16, userfield);
                    insSt.setObject(17, newcost);
                    //executing the insert statement
                    insSt.executeUpdate();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                //closing the resources in this transaction
                try {
                    //the insSt statement doesn't have a resultset
                    if (insSt != null) {
                        insSt.close();
                    }
                    //the rst ResultSet is bounded to stmt Statement, it must be closed first
                    if (rst != null) {
                        rst.close();
                    }
                    if (stmt != null) {
                        stmt.close();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {}
            }
        } else if (AreaCode.equals(str2)) {
            System.out.println("Hii2");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} finally {
    //closing the resources in this transaction
    //similar logic than the used in the last close block code
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (st != null) {
            st.close();
        }
        //at the last of all the operations, close the connection
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {}
}
```

---

As a side note, the fact that you're a beginner doesn't mean that you should code the thing *just to make it work*. You should **always** follow the best practices. IMO it's good to ask for guidance in these scenarios.

Comment: @Ram if the answer works for your case, please mark it as an answer (click in the check next to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into cdrcost (
         calldate,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,
         dstchannel,lastapp, lastdata,duration,billsec,
         disposition,amaflags,accountcode,uniqueid,
         userfield,cdrcost) values ('" + calldate + "','" + 
         clid + "','" + src + "','" + dst + "','" + dcontext 
         + "','" + channel + "','" + dstchannel + "','" + 
         lastapp + "','" + lastdata + "','" + duration + "','" + 
         billsec + "','" + disposition + "','" + amaflags 
          + "','" + accountcode + "','" + uniqueid + "','" + userfield  
         + "','" + newcost + "')");
```

Here, when you execute this `update` inside the `while` loop then the current `resultset` of the previous `select` query will get closed. So you cannot do `res.next()` in the next iteration.

If you want to `hold` data after disconnecting, you can use `Cached Row Set`:

```
ResultSet res = ....
CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
rowset.populate(res);
```

CachedRowSet is a connectionless ResultSet. I have not used it much, because I didn't have any need. But, I can share some link here to help you understand the concepts

- http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html
- [Where to close a JDBC Connection while I want to return the ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910049/where-to-close-a-jdbc-connection-while-i-want-to-return-the-resultset)

Or you can better take a look at [RowSetFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetFactory.html) which provides you with method `createCachedRowSet()` that can create `CachedRowSet` instance for you.

You can get `RowSetFactory` from [RowSetProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html). Then you can get `CachedRowSet` and iterate over it.

```
RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
CachedRowSet crs = factory.createCachedRowSet();
crs.populate(res);

while(crs.next()) {
    crs.getString(1);  // Works similar to `ResultSet`
}
```

Comment: @Rohit Jain .. Thank you Sir for ur quick reply ..will u plz guide me how to correct

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Don't worry, I'll wait next time before answering. Will give you full chance :) :P

Comment: You can propose a solution in order to give a better answer. Also, OP should use the same connection for all the operations, no need to open a new `Connection` for every result in the first `ResultSet`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza then how to correct this error sir .really i dont have any idea ..plz help me sir

Comment: @RohitJain Sir where to put CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
rowset.populate(res);
 inseide the while (res.next) loop or out side to this

Comment: @Ram I'm preparing an answer that will suit for your case and will help you to understand the basics of JDBC.

Comment: @Ram. No you can use CachedRowSet in place of `ResultSet` and iterate over it `crc.next()` similar to what you do with `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

At a given point of time, a connection can be used by only one statement. The resultsets that are a result of executing the statement share the same connection. So, if you want to perform an update for each row while reading it from result set, you should request for an UPDATEABLE result set while creating the statement, then update the column in the current row in place while browsing through the resultset.

Since you seem to need to insert a record into a different table, you can do one of the following:

1. Use cached row sets

   1. Get your resultset into a [`CachedRowSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html).
   2. Close the result set and statement.
   3. Iterate through the cached row set and create a statement for each insertion and execute it.
2. Use separate objects to track what needs to be inserted

   1. Build the to-be-inserted records as objects into a list.
   2. Once done with the resultset, close it, close the statement.
   3. prepare a new statement i.e. PreparedStatement, for the INSERT statement.
   4. insert the records as a batch.
3. Worst-case, use three connections, one for outer query, one for inner query and one for insertion

The following code (not at all production-quality, but just a dirty implementation of third option above):

```
    try
    {
        // used for outer query.
        Connection outerCon = null;
        // used for inner query.
        Connection innerCon = null;
        // used to insert records.
        Connection insCon = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        outerCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
        innerCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
        insCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
        Statement st = outerCon.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from asteriskcdrdb.sp1");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            AreaCode = rs.getString("AreaCode");
            // System.out.println(AreaCode);
            String Pulse = rs.getString("Pulse");
            Rate = rs.getInt("Rate/pulse");
            // System.out.println(Rate);
            if (AreaCode.equals(str))
            {
                System.out.println("Hii");
                try
                {
                    Statement stmt = innerCon.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from cdr where src ='9035020090'");
                    while (rst.next())
                    {
                        calldate = rst.getString("calldate");
                        // System.out.println(calldate);
                        clid = rst.getString("clid");
                        src = rst.getString("src");
                        dst = rst.getString("dst");
                        dcontext = rst.getString("dcontext");
                        channel = rst.getString("channel");
                        dstchannel = rst.getString("dstchannel");
                        lastapp = rst.getString("lastapp");
                        lastdata = rst.getString("lastdata");
                        duration = rst.getString("duration");
                        // System.out.println(duration);
                        dur = Integer.parseInt(duration);
                        // System.out.println(dur);
                        data.add(dur);
                        billsec = rst.getString("billsec");
                        disposition = rst.getString("disposition");
                        amaflags = rst.getString("amaflags");
                        accountcode = rst.getString("accountcode");
                        uniqueid = rst.getString("uniqueid");
                        userfield = rst.getString("userfield");
                        int newcost = checktime(dur, Rate);
                        Statement insStmt = insCon.createStatement();
                        stmt
                            .executeUpdate("insert into cdrcost (calldate,clid,src,dst,dcontext,channel,dstchannel,lastapp, lastdata,duration,billsec,disposition,amaflags,accountcode,uniqueid,userfield,cdrcost) values ('"
                                + calldate
                                + "','"
                                + clid
                                + "','"
                                + src
                                + "','"
                                + dst
                                + "','"
                                + dcontext
                                + "','"
                                + channel
                                + "','"
                                + dstchannel
                                + "','"
                                + lastapp
                                + "','"
                                + lastdata
                                + "','"
                                + duration
                                + "','"
                                + billsec
                                + "','"
                                + disposition
                                + "','"
                                + amaflags
                                + "','"
                                + accountcode + "','" + uniqueid + "','" + userfield + "','" + newcost + "')");
                        insStmt.close();
                    }
                    rst.close();
                    stmt.close();

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            else if (AreaCode.equals(str2))
            {
                System.out.println("Hii2");
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: as suggested in the response, you can use one of those two methods. Are you looking for anything specific?

Comment: Sir i am very new to the programmin field and really have never used this ...So plz help me with my code ...Plz sir

Comment: Please see the update about a third option and modifications to your code to implement that.